# HTML5 Footer Navigation

Tags: css, html, wordpress

Recently I'm in charge of a CMS project from my client.

[image]

But I have no idea how to approach this layout.

I use the code below to generate footer navigation bar.

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
height: 150px;
width: 100%;
```

I'm also using Master Slider to generator the slider.
And now I'm having a problem how to make the website become responsive.

I try to apply 80% height for carousel; and 20% height for footer.
But I don't think it can work.

And this is the layout so far I created without any responsive function.

Is there an efficient way to create this kind of responsive layout?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider that responsive doesn't necessarily (or rather "hardly ever") means that the same design should be visible on all the devices.

Think **content first**, which is an approach to deliver the content of your website to the user in a clear way that doesn't overcomplicate. It's "function over form", where the design comes after a good User Experience, IMHO.

Therefore, and if you are still working on developing the static versions of the website, I would start working on the mobile website, where the design and content has to be synthesized, and gradually expand to bigger devices.

In this case, this might mean a new and different navigation for the mobile website instead of the footer menu.

Hopefully this will lead you in the right direction.

Comment: As @Johnny pointed out, if you make responsive, think first about content before you even go meddling with awesome looking futures. A website remains a way to distribute information, as for you it is to strive for marketing goals. Keep always that in mind. Remove fance looking items if it doesnt work on responsive design.

Comment: I see. This layout is come from my company designer. So what I have to do is follow my designer work. I have no choice.